# I created a form which will be displayed inside a table. When the information is already inside the table it should allow me to edit it

Tags: javascript, button, edit

```
$('#dependents-info').on('click', '.btn-edit-dependent', function () {
                var currentTD = $(this).closest("tr");
                $('#modal2').modal({ show: true });
            });
```

This is the code for edit button. I can't get the previous value of the modal where I created it.

Comment: is what the selector element "$('#dependents-info')" is loaded into the dom when you load your javascript ?